# Shortcut to jquery selector for several input controls in an ASP.NET web page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there any shortcut or best way for using jquery control selector in an ASP.NET web page which has more than 70 to 80 input controls?

Atpresent, I am grouping all the initialization in a method as shown below and calling this method in the DOM ready event,

```
function CreateControlObjects()
{
var userNameTxtBox = $('#UserNameTxtBox');
var userDOBTxtBox = $('#UserDOBTxtBox');
... (80 more controls...)
}
```

Once these control objects are created, I am using them for getting/setting values as shown below,

```
var UserInput = {};
UserInput.UserName = $.trim(userNameTxtBox.val());
....
```

This CreateControlObjects function is growing and I feel little hard to maintain... 
So, is there any best way to handle this?

Thanks in advance,
Vim

Comment: Give them a pseudo class eg class=".textbox" and a data-attribute then do $('.textbox').each(function(){ UserInput[$(this).data('name')] = $.trim($(this).val())}

Comment: I think an MVVM approach could help you here. Look into [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), [KendoUI MVVM](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/index), or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks Dave. As most of our users are still using IE8, I am little hesitated to move towards Angular js and latest javascript frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I'll give this as an answer to make it more clear.

You can do for example.

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" data-name="UserName" />

function CreateControlObjects()
{
   var UserInput = {};
   $('.textbox').each(function(){
       UserInput[$(this).data('name')] = $.trim($(this).val());
   });
}
```